# Accented letters disappeared in old .tex files but not in new ones

Tags: xetex, texstudio

I have a weird problem where my existing .tex files are suddenly incapable of rendering accented characters. But when I start a completely new file, it does work. What could cause this? I stripped down one of my old files completely down to this MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\begin{document}    
    Unsöld
\end{document}
```

which gives this output

[image]

but if I copy that exact same code to a new file and save that file in the same directory, it suddenly works as expected? What could cause this problem? I tried deleting all generated files but that did not fix the problem.

I run XeLateX and use TeXstudio as IDE.

Comment: presumably your old files are not in utf-8 but your editor saves them in utf-8 on copy.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was due to erroneous encoding applied to the file.

Comment: I can also delete it? Not sure if there is any reason to preserve the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David Carlisle noted, I accidently changed the encoding of my file when I opened it with a different text editor.